# Scripting language choice

Tags: python, scripting, f#, xna, lua

I am evaluating options for a scripting language to embed at my company.

We mostly make indie games, and we use managed frameworks (Unity and XNA). This means that we need a solution that works with both Mono and .Net, and we'd rather avoid stuff that is too slow.

The possibilities we are considering are the following:

1. python
2. lua
3. F#

The features we require are:

1. continuations/coroutines
2. decent performance
3. integration with Mono and .Net (compatible type systems)
4. [optional]. ease of extensibility to add new combinators such as multithreaded coroutines
5. [optional]. easy bindings

I know for certain that I can achieve all requirements in F# with a custom-built monad (I have several working prototypes which are ending in a few products) but I would gladly jump to another solution if it is proven to be better!

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you don't like about F#?  If you know that it meets all of your requirements, what are the factors that would lead you to choose another language?

Comment: This is way too broad. What will the scripting language will be used for?

Comment: Have a look at Nemerle. It supports functional and OOP styles, but also provides very powerful metaprogramming capabilities which enable you to extend the language syntax to suit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

As you're using .net anyway, any of the .net languages might allow you the easiest implementations. From a learning perspective etc. I'd prefer Lua any time due to it's rather simple basic constructs and syntax rules.

Answer (score 1):

I have a weird-er suggestion for you. How about using C# or VB.NET?
You can dynamically compile scripts and save the assemblies. This way you get minimum loading time.
You can also register them in the GAC and have no worry!